# what are the differences between \\?\pipe\ and \\.\pipe\ named pipe namespaces in Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, sockets, ipc, named-pipes

I am moving an application from gRPC (which is forcibly TCP and causes Windows Firewall to pop up and bother our users with a decision they don't understand) to do IPC instead via domain sockets on linux/macOS and named pipes on Windows using `node:net`, and it mentions on [its documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#identifying-paths-for-ipc-connections):

> The path must refer to an entry in `\\?\pipe\` or `\\.\pipe\`. Any characters are permitted, but the latter may do some processing of pipe names, such as resolving `..` sequences. Despite how it might look, the pipe namespace is flat.

But I don't understand what's the differences of these namespaces (and haven't found anything on Google because it doesn't search for ? and .)

I'm thinking the `\\.\pipe` one is relative to the current (working) directory and the `\\?\` is its own kind of root? But I don't have official documentation about it. Would like to know before shipping it to production because if that's the difference then I'm inclined to `\\?\` and that's what  have in my code right now hehe

Comment: https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html

Comment: @HansPassant ok I see the Root Local Device now. I wonder how it acts with pipes